# Eclipse export to zipped file requires a refresh

Tags: eclipse

I use export to a zipped file to make temporary backups of my project.

Sometimes the export fails and eclipse prints an error message. If I refresh then try again, the export goes without error.

Is there some way to have eclipse automatically do a refresh before it starts the export?

Comment: What is the error? Is it 'File out of synch' or something to that effect? That error means something has changed some of your file out of eclipse.